# How to fill in values of a dataframe column if the difference between values in another column is sufficiently small?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe df1:

```
      Time    Delta_time
0     0       NaN               
1     15      15    
2     18      3 
3     30      12    
4     45      15    
5     64      19    
6     80      16    
7     82      2 
8     100     18    
9     120     20
```

where Delta_time is the difference between adjacent values in the Time column. I have another dataframe df2 that has time values numbering from 0 to 120 (121 rows) and another column called 'Short_gap'.

How do I set the value of Short_gap to 1 for all Time values that lie in a Delta_time value smaller than 5? For example, the Short_gap column should have a value of 1 for Time = 15,16,17,18 since Delta_time = 3 < 5.

**Edit**: Currently, df2 looks like this.

```
      Time   Short_gap
0     0      0              
1     1      0
2     2      0
3     3      0
...   ...    ...    
118   118    0
119   119    0
120   120    0
```

The expected output for df2 is

```
      Time   Short_gap
0     0      0
1     1      0
2     2      0
...   ...    ...    
13    13     0
14    14     0
15    15     1
16    16     1
17    17     1
18    18     1
19    19     0
20    20     0
...   ...    ...
78    78     0
79    79     0
80    80     1
81    81     1
82    82     1
83    83     0
84    84     0
...   ...    ...
119   119    0
120   120    0
```

Comment: Please provide `df2` and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
t = df['Delta_time'].shift(-1)
df2 = ((t < 5).repeat(t.fillna(1)).astype(int).reset_index(drop=True)
      .to_frame(name='Short_gap').rename_axis('Time').reset_index())
print(df2.head(20))
print('...')
print(df2.loc[78:84])
```

Output:

```
    Time  Short_gap
0      0          0
1      1          0
2      2          0
3      3          0
4      4          0
5      5          0
6      6          0
7      7          0
8      8          0
9      9          0
10    10          0
11    11          0
12    12          0
13    13          0
14    14          0
15    15          1
16    16          1
17    17          1
18    18          0
19    19          0
...
    Time  Short_gap
78    78          0
79    79          0
80    80          1
81    81          1
82    82          0
83    83          0
84    84          0
```